# linq - create a list of integers from a list of objects

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hy!

I'm trying to create a list of days(integer) from a list of dates(date).

I tryed to do this.....

```
Dim days As New List(Of Integer)
days = From a In DATES
                Where a.desc = "ferias"
                Select Day(a.date)
```

But Im getting an error saying that its

> not possible to convert an object of type
>   "WhereSelectListIterar"'2[dates, System.int32] in
>   system.collections.generic.list'1[System.int32]

How can I get the integer days of "DATES", which is a list of Date?

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't do Dim days As New List(Of Integer) if you intend to overwrite this value. Next, use the ToList() extension method if you want a list instead of an enumerable.

```
Dim days As List(Of Integer) = _
    (From a In DATES _
     Where a.desc = "ferias" _
     Select Day(a.date)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim days as As List(Of Integer) = dates.ConvertAll(Of Integer)(Function(D As Date) D.Day)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do something like this:

```
  days = (From a In dates
                    Where a.desc= "ferias"
                    Select a.date.Day).ToList
```

You need to .ToList the result.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to list using ToList as:

```
Dim days As New List(Of Integer)
days = (From a In DATES
                Where a.desc = "ferias"
                Select Day(a.date)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on the result of the Linq expression.